# Change link color with javascript for style defined by scss

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have scss than looks something like

```
#container{
   a{
      color:white;
   }
}
```

And I would like to change the links to another color using javascript. IE

```
function changeColorTo(color){
   //insert help here
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can apply a style locally on an element and it will override the stylesheet rule.

```
function changeColorTo(color){
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var anchors = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i<anchors.length; i++){
        anchors[i].style.color = color;
    }
}
```

edits: i'm dumb, i get what you want to do now. sample updated.

Comment: This changes all the links on the entire page. Which i guess i useful, but what I really need is to change only the links in the #container section.

Comment: sorry, i overlooked that part. i updated my answer to address that.

Comment: How can I use this to change the ```a:hover``` colour?

Answer (score 2):

Solution from lincolnk works prefectly, however if using jQuery this also works

```
$('#container a').css('color',color)
```

So, yeah, jQuery is kind of sweet.